# Appendix after each chapter

Tags: chapters, appendices

How can I add an appendix with two or 3 sections **after** each chapter in a book?

Comment: One immediate question would be the nomenclature for the appendices.  After chapter 2, for example, how would you like the appendices numbered?  How should figures, tables, equations in these appendices be numbered?

Comment: Appendix 2A, 2B, the figures could be like figure 2A.1 and the equations 2B.1. Also I would like this appendix to be shown in the Table of contents (the title only).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `subappendices` environment from the [`appendix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package could be useful here:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{A regular section}
\section{Another regular section}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{A regular section}
\section{Another regular section}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

An image of the first page of appendices for one of the chapters:

[image]

Comment: why we are using \lipsum[4]?

Comment: @Ome to easily generate filling text.

Comment: Can this method be applied to add appendices at the end of `Part` sections with multiple chapters within? I have opened a question thread for my specific case here and I would appreciate any input: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188387/koma-script-scrreprt-how-to-add-appendix-for-each-part-section

Comment: Nice answer. However, the theorems in the added appendices get numbered in the same  way as in the usual text. Can you say how to arrange for the theorems to bear the name of the appendix?

Answer (score 12):

The (correct) answer given by @Gonzalo causes the numbering of tables and figures to reset in regular sections following an appendix. This is due to the `\counterwithin` command that is called at the beginning of the `subappendices` environment. To prevent this, one needs to revert to `\counterwithout` at the end of the `subappendices` environment:

```
% Start of subappendices environment
\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
\chapter*{Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
}

% End of subappendices environment
\AtEndEnvironment{subappendices}{%
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\counterwithout{table}{section}
}
```