# KOMA-Script scrreprt: How to add Appendix for each Part section

Tags: koma-script, appendices, parts

**EDIT (SOLVED)** The below answer by LaRiFaRi successfully allowed me to introduce appendicies where desired, however they have a serious issue with the minitoc. After the first appendix the next chapter loses its minitoc. This does not happen if the appendix is included as `\appendix` however this does cause every successive chapter to be an appendix (unless there is a known way to stop this command?).
Please could you help fix the interaction between the two? The updated MWE from the original one is included at the bottom of this post.

**Original post**

I have subdivided my thesis into several parts since they are based on different methods employed. To make things more readable and light I want to move certain common information within each part to an appendix.

How can I insert appendices that show up just at the end of the part section rather than at the end of the entire document?

I know I could add a chapter rather than an appendix for this, however an appendix makes much more sense. Please find my MWE below with my customised chapter heading style with a TOC, Part and Chapter.

```
\documentclass[
bibliography=totoc,
headings=big,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true% like in standard class "report"
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % number subsubsections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % list subsubsections

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{4}{\color{gray}\thechapter}\enskip}}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{page}{199}
\newpage\setcounter{page}{212}

\part{Introduction}

\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}

\minitoc



\section{Summary of Achievements}
Text goes here

\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text

\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATED MWE**

```
\documentclass[
bibliography=totoc,
headings=big,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true% like in standard class "report"
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % number subsubsections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % list subsubsections

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{4}{\color{gray}\thechapter}\enskip}}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{page}{199}
\newpage\setcounter{page}{212}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\part{Introduction}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}

\minitoc

\section{Summary of Achievements}
Text goes here

\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text

\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out


%%%%% APPENDIX
\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Some Appendix}
The contents...
\end{appendices}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\part{Introduction}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{The No MiniTOC Chapter}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}

\minitoc

\section{Unfortunate Problems}
This chapter does not have a minitoc for some reason

\subsection{Still no minitoc}
Text

\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
Testing stuff out

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}

\minitoc

\section{Summary of Achievements}
Text goes here

\subsection{Papers Submitted}
Text



\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With help of the package `appendix` you can add an appendix whenever you want. When using this package and when using one of the KOMA-classes, `minitoc` writes the following into the `.log`-file:

> Package minitoc(hints) Info: I0042
>        (minitoc(hints)) --- The appendix package is loaded.
>
> (minitoc(hints))             See the minitoc package documentation
>
> (minitoc(hints))             for specific precautions.
>
> Package minitoc(hints) Info: I0043
>
> (minitoc(hints))             --- The KOMAScript scrreprt class is
>   loaded.
>
> (minitoc(hints))             See the minitoc package documentation
>
> (minitoc(hints))             for specific precautions.

I looked in the [minitoc package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) and adapted the code for you. But you should definitely read the chapters 1.5.5, 2.20, and 2.35 as you will run in several other problems when adding lof, lot, bib, and so on.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[
bibliography=totoc,
headings=big,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true% like in standard class "report"
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{appendix}
\let\oldappendices\appendices
\def\appendices{\oldappendices\addtocontents{toc}{\chapterend}} % <----------   set a chapter end mark after each appendix.
\usepackage{blindtext} % <----------   for demo.

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{4}{\color{gray}\thechapter}\enskip}}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{page}{199}
\newpage\setcounter{page}{212}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\part{Introduction}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}
\minitoc
\section{Summary of Achievements}
\blindtext
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
\blindtext
%%%%% APPENDIX
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Some Appendix}
\blindtext
\end{appendices}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\part{Introduction}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{The No MiniTOC Chapter}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}
\minitoc
\section{Unfortunate Problems}
This chapter does not have a minitoc for some reason
\subsection{Still no minitoc}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
\blindtext
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}
\minitoc
\section{Summary of Achievements}
\blindtext
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Ah that certainly works, I didn't realise this package wasn't the same as the functions within `scrreprt`! Do you know whether there is a way to remove the `Appendices` page as a package setting by any chance?

Comment: Ah figured it out, just had to change the command to `\usepackage[toc]{appendix}`

Comment: Would you happen to know how to insert a minitoc inside the appendix environment? Or how to end the `\appendix` command since that allows the inclusion of a minitoc?

Comment: Sorry I am going to have to revoke the correct answer as actually this system works but with a lot of issues that I have not been able to remedy throughout the afternoon. Please could you or anyone else assist.

Comment: @Fiztban: I do not want to diminish LaRiFaRi's answer, but an appendix is basically nothing more than additional chapter or section with corresponding subsection(s)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I understand this and i realise that I could make a special adaptation of the chapter style to make it into an appendix like chapter, but if there is a package combination that is capable of doing this it would make life easier.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thank you for your update, I will read through those chapters and see what I can implement, your changed MWE still doesn't solve the minitoc problems once the appendices is added for that example. I think the easiest thing at this point would be to simply edit the counter for that given chapter to write appendix instead of chapter and have A instead of a number. Not too sure how to figure out the command to do that but research will help :) I have accepted your answer again, I highly appreciate your help and effort.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi again thank you, maybe its a problem of testing out stuff on sharelatex.com, I will try it in my TeXStudio and see. It does describe it in detail, somehow LaTeX documentation still takes me a lot of effort to digest, its a steep learning curve, I'm sure I will get past the hard soon enough :)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I can confirm it doesn't work in my TexStudio either.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi ah, if the line `\mtcaddchapter` is edited out it works fine for your example.

Comment: @Fiztban see my last version. This should work fine. If you comment `\mtcaddchapter` in my previous solution, you won't get the minitoc of chapter 7.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi thank you, it works well now, it seems that having the `[toc]` in `\usepackage[toc]{appendix}` is also an element that is responsible for messing up the minitoc. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: It seems the problem got solved somewhere before the current version of minitoc `2015/07/13 v61`