# Can a chapter style environment be used for appendix formatting?

Tags: environments, chapters, koma-script, appendices

I have started including appendices in my thesis to collate common information for each separate `\part` section so as to make the script concise and to the point. I am using a `KOMA-Script` document class: `scrreprt`, using the `appendix` package together with the `minitoc` package for my chapter format style has been giving me a real headache, though it is [solved (in my previously asked question)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188387/koma-script-scrreprt-how-to-add-appendix-for-each-part-section) for the most part, the result was unsatisfactory as I cannot include a `\minitoc` inside the appendix.

My solution was to go manual and simply change `\chaptername` name to appendix and the and `\thechapter` numbering to `\Alph{chapter}` and subsequently also change the `\setcounter` so as to get the chapter lettering to start where desired.

This of course meant I had to put it all back at the end of the appendix chapter so that all following chapters would continue unaffected. I was wondering whether there is a way to simply define an environment that sets these parameters (chapter > appendix, chapter numbering > letter, chapter counter) and that allows for the chapter counter to continue between the instances of each repeated environment such that when I put my first environment at the end of the first part it will be called `Appendix A` and once I put the next one at the end of the second part it will automatically continue form the numbering of the previous environment resulting in `Appendix B`.

If there is a relatively simple way to do this by defining an environment I would gladly implement that over the manual approach I employed in the below MWE.

```
\documentclass[
bibliography=totoc,
headings=big,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true% like in standard class "report"
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{4}{\color{gray}\thechapter}\enskip}}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{page}{199}
\newpage\setcounter{page}{212}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\part{Introduction}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}
\minitoc
\section{Summary of Achievements}
\blindtext
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
\blindtext

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% APPENDIX
% Chapter style change for Appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Experimental Appendices}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}

\chapter{Test}

\minitoc

Here goes nothing

\section{Adding it all in}
Done

% Chapter style reset for following chapters
\setcounter{chapter}{7}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\part{Introduction}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{The No MiniTOC Chapter}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}
\minitoc
\section{Unfortunate Problems}
This chapter does not have a minitoc for some reason
\subsection{Still no minitoc}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
\blindtext
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}
\minitoc
\section{Summary of Achievements}
\blindtext
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but I do not have time right now to post an answer. I come back later on.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you for your reply and thank you for any further help you offer when time permits, I appreciate!

Comment: See my answer, perhaps it provides what you request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve the OP's request, some aspects must be considered:

- Restore the chapter number of a **true** chapter
- Restore the running appendix number
- Restore the counter output formats

Additionally one has to keep in mind

- Should it be a command such as `\appendix`

  If this is the case, the restore of settings is a little difficult, but can be done, see below.
- Should it be an environment, say `partappendix`
  In this case, wrap the settings inside the environments starting and end code sections, best protected by `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` and restore only the chapter counter in the end code section of the environment.

The principal steps are the same for the setup of the appendix chapter, therefore I defined the `\partappendix@@setup` command, which sets the corresponding values and does some redefinitions. This command is called in `\appendix`. However, the changes must be reversed at that time when a new true chapter is opened, so I decided, that this is the case, when a new `\part` starts, so I let `\part` do the reversal of settings to the 'standard' values.
--> Redefine `\part` and its fellows.

**Note: There must be no true additional `\chapter` after `\appendix` with this approach.**

The usage of

```
\begin{partappendix}[options]{Appendix Name}
\section{First}
\end[partappendix}
```

allows additional true `\chapter` commands after the environment `partappendix`, although this is rather unlikely.

**Description of options and arguments to `\appendix` and `partappendix` environment**

- MiniTOC=true/false   --> True (default) -> automatically use a `\minitoc` at the start of the appendix
- TOCEntry={}          --> Provides a short title as entry to the TOC, otherwise `\Appendixname~\thechapter` is used.

---

```
\documentclass[%
bibliography=totoc,
headings=big,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true% like in standard class "report"
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\newcommand{\mk}[1]{%

}%

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xkeyval}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%  
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}%


\newcounter{resumechaptercounter}%
\newcounter{resumeappendixcounter}%

\makeatletter
% First save some definitions%
\let\LaTeXStandardChapterName\chaptername%
\let\LaTeXStandardTheChapter\thechapter%
\let\LaTeXStandardAppendix\appendix%
\let\LaTeXStandardPart\part%

% Provide the resetting code for some definitions by the renewcommanded \appendix
\newcommand{\part@@pre@mblecode}{%
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\LaTeXStandardChapterName}%
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\LaTeXStandardTheChapter}%
\ifnumgreater{\number\value{resumechaptercounter}}{0}{%
\setcounter{chapter}{\number\value{resumechaptercounter}}%
}{}%
}%

%%%% Provide new part code with optional argument
\newcommand{\unstarredpart@opt}[2][]{%
\part@@pre@mblecode%
\LaTeXStandardPart[#1]{#2}%
}%

%%%% Provide new part code without optional argument

\newcommand{\unstarredpart@noopt}[1]{%
\unstarredpart@opt[#1]{#1}%
}%

%%%% Provide a new \part*{} code in order to relax \tableofcontents
\newcommand{\starredpart}[1]{%
\part@@pre@mblecode%
\LaTeXStandardPart*{#1}%
}%


\newcommand{\unstarredpart}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarredpart@opt}{\unstarredpart@noopt}%
}%

%%%% The real redefinition of \part%
%%% Comment it out in order to keep the standard \part behaviour, but
%%% in this case do not use the new \appendix command, only \begin{partappendix} ... \end{partappendix}
\renewcommand{\part}{%
\@ifstar{\starredpart}{\unstarredpart}%
}%




% Create a switch if the minitoc should be enabled in
% an appendix 'chapter' too. 
\newtoggle{MiniTOC}%


\define@boolkey{PartAppendix}{MiniTOC}[true]{%
\ifKV@PartAppendix@MiniTOC%
\toggletrue{MiniTOC}%
\else%
\togglefalse{MiniTOC}%
\fi%
}%

\define@key{PartAppendix}{TOCEntry}[]{%
\def\PartAppendixKVMacroTOCEntry{#1}%
}%

%This is the appendix setup, which stores the current
% chapter counter and changes the \thechapter, name etc.
\newcommand{\partappendix@@setup}[2][]{%
\setkeys{PartAppendix}{MiniTOC=true,#1}%
\setcounter{resumechaptercounter}{\number\value{chapter}}% Backup 
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\appendixname}
\setcounter{chapter}{\number\value{resumeappendixcounter}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\refstepcounter{resumeappendixcounter}%
\phantomsection%
\ifdef{\PartAppendixKVMacroTOCEntry}{%
\chapter[\PartAppendixKVMacroTOCEntry]{#2}%
}{%
\chapter{#2}%
}%
\iftoggle{MiniTOC}{%
  \minitoc
}{}%
}%

% Renew the appendix command
\renewcommand{\appendix}[2][]{%
\partappendix@@setup[#1]{#2}%
}%


\newenvironment{partappendix}[2][]{%
\begingroup%
\appendix[#1]{#2}%
}{%
\endgroup%
\setcounter{chapter}{\number\value{resumechaptercounter}}% Restore the chapter number%
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\huge}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{4}{\color{gray}\thechapter}\enskip}}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{page}{199}
\newpage\setcounter{page}{212}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\part{Introduction}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}
\minitoc
\section{Summary of Achievements}
\blindtext
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC}
\blindtext

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% APPENDIX


\begin{partappendix}{Test}


\section{Adding it all in}
Done

\end{partappendix}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\part{Introduction}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{The no more No MiniTOC Chapter}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}
\minitoc
\section{Luckily no more unfortunate problems}
This chapter does have a minitoc again
\subsection{Still has a minitoc}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{I want to go into the TOC and there I am}
\blindtext
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Conclusions}
\dictum[Sun Tzu]{If you know the enemy and you know yourself %\\
you need not fear the results of a hundred battles.}
\minitoc
\section{Summary of Achievements}
\blindtext
\subsection{Papers Submitted}
\blindtext

\begin{partappendix}[TOCEntry={2nd Part Appendix}]{Appendix from second part}

\section{William}
\subsection{Hamlet}%
\subsubsection{Yorick's skull}
\blindtext

\section{Shakespeare}

\end{partappendix}


\appendix[MiniTOC=false]{AnotherAppendix from second part}

\section{Gandalf}
\subsection{Shadowfax}
\section{Frodo}
\subsection{Sting}
\section{Samwise}%
\subsection{Samwise's Uncle}
\subsubsection{Samwise's Art of gardening and cooking rabbits}
\subsubsection{Gollum's distaste of Samwise's cooking arts}%
\part{Dummy part}
\chapter{Dummy chapter}

\appendix{New Appendix from the dummy part}

\section{A dummy appendix section}%

\end{document}
```

Here are some screen shots of the TOC, chapter 8 starting page with minitoc and of Appendix B

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Note** Although I have intermixed `\appendix` and `\begin{partappendix} ...\end{partappendix}` style as a method of demonstration, I would refrain from doing so in production code. Use the environment for 'safety'.

**Other note**: I did not test for any eventuality so far (who can do this anyway)

Comment: This is absolutely stunning, the extent of customisability included has left me speechless!! I literally have no negative feedback or minor bugs to report after testing it for a while. Thank you ever so much for your help!

Comment: @Fiztban: In your original MWE you have some `\addcontentsline` statements, I omitted them, as I was unsure about the leveling you desire. If you find some bug(s) please leave a comment or write a mail (see my profile).

Comment: @ChristianHumpfer Indeed I did notice, but it's not a problem I have already re-written those just so as to have a slight detachment from the TOC elements to identify it as a separate part from the rest. Thank you, I will keep you informed if anything comes up

Comment: @Fiztban: Well then, happy `TeXing` ;-)