# Thesis table of contents: including chapter-specific appendices immediately after their respective chapters, rather than all at the end

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm wrapping up my dissertation and my table of contents currently reads along these lines:

- 1. chapter one

     - 1.1 section one
     - 1.2 section two
- 2. chapter two

     - 2.1 section one
     - 2.2 section two
- A.  appendix for chapter one
- B.  appendix for chapter two

if at all possible, i'd really like to be able to do something along these lines:

- 1. chapter one

     - 1.1 section one
     - 1.2 section two
     - 1.A appendix
- 2. chapter two

     - 2.1 section one
     - 2.2 section two
     - 2.A appendix

does anyone know how to do this sort of thing? thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Thank you for the quick reply @Au101. ideally i'd like the actual appendix to chapter one to come before the actual start of chapter two. i am pretty experienced with latex, but this is my first time putting together a book-like document rather than just an individual article...

Comment: Do you want that behaviour just in the table of contents, but with the actual appendices themselves all at the back - or do you actually want the appendix to chapter one itself to come before the start of chapter two. In both cases, but especially if it's just the table of contents - my friend, I hope you know what you're doing ... :P

Comment: P.S. Welcome to TeX.SE. You'll probably find that you'll get better answers if you include a minimum working example: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. It will certainly likely be nicer for us to help you. For example, the solution may change if you've loaded a package like `etoc` or have modified your table of contents in some more basic way

Comment: @ABD  Welcome! Instead of adding comments in the answer block, you can click the `add a comment` button to reply to commentators.

Comment: @ABD: An appendix is basically nothing else than an additional `\chapter` or `\section`, with another counting/numbering style, most probably. This is possible of course, but appendix means: to append ... at the end ;-) It looks rather weird to have just an Appendix `1A`. why  `1A` when there's no `1B`?

Comment: you want to format appendix (contents of appendix in the body) as sections following corresponding chapters or just costum the table of contents

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/appendix-after-each-chapter

Answer (score 2):

Some weird code-golfing with `xparse` and a slightly (;-)) modified `\section` command -- do not use `\subsection` there!

I just added a 4th optional argument to `\section`, which is a `*`, indicating that this should be an appendix section, going right here, not at the end of the document. (well, a chapter appendix then)

It will break if another 'normal' `\section` will follow.

All is reset if the next `\chapter` comes into action.

And there is some warning by `hyperref`, but the links work.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{appsection}[chapter]

\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter

\let\latex@section\section
\let\latex@thesection\thesection

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{soms}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@section*{#4}
  }{%
    \IfBooleanT{#4}{%
      \ifnumgreater{\value{appsection}}{0}{%
      }{%
        \setcounter{section}{0}%
        \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Alph{appsection}}%
        \renewcommand{\theHsection}{\thechapter.\Alph{appsection}}%
      }
      \stepcounter{appsection}%
    }%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@section[#2]{#3}%
    }{%
      \latex@section{#3}%
    }%  
  }%
}



% Restore the section number format. 
\xpretocmd{\chapter}{\renewcommand{\thesection}{\latex@thesection}}{}{}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{First appendix}*

\chapter{Second}
\blindtext[10]
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\clearpage
\section{First appendix}*
\blindtext[10]
\clearpage
\section{Second appendix}*
\blindtext[10]


\chapter{Third}
\blindtext[10]
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Fourth section}
\clearpage
\section{First appendix}*
\blindtext[10]
\clearpage
\section{Second appendix}*
\blindtext[10]

\section{Third appendix}*
\blindtext[10]




\end{document}
```

**Update** Improved interface and preventing sections to be added after some section has been declared as `appendix` section. It automatically adds a `Appendix` and a clearpage. `subsections` etc. work as expected as well as references.

The macro call is `\section![toc title]{body title}` if is meant to be an appendix section at the end of the chapter. If `!` is omitted, the standard command is used.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{appsection}[chapter]
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=5]{hyperref}


\makeatletter

\newif\ifappsectionclearpage
\appsectionclearpagetrue

\newif\ifappsection
\appsectionfalse

\let\latex@section\section
\let\latex@thesection\thesection

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{st!om}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@section*{#4}
  }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
      \appsectiontrue%
      \ifnumgreater{\value{appsection}}{0}{%
      }{%
        \setcounter{section}{0}%
        \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Alph{appsection}}%
        \renewcommand{\theHsection}{\thechapter.\arabic{appsection}}%
      }
      \stepcounter{appsection}%
      \ifappsectionclearpage
      \clearpage
      \fi
      \IfValueTF{#3}{%
        \latex@section[#3]{\appendixname~#4}%
      }{%
        \latex@section{\appendixname~#4}%
      }%    
    }{%
      \ifappsection
      %% Nothing in here!
      \else
      \IfValueTF{#3}{%
        \latex@section[#3]{#4}%
      }{%
        \latex@section{#4}%
      }%    
      \fi
    }%
  }%
}




\xpretocmd{\chapter}{\renewcommand{\thesection}{\latex@thesection}\protect\appsectionfalse}{}{}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section!{First appendix}

In \ref{thirdapp:thirdchap} we will see that

\chapter{Second}
\blindtext[10]
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\clearpage
\section!{First appendix}
\blindtext[10]
\clearpage
\section!{Second appendix}
\blindtext[10]


\chapter{Third}
\blindtext[10]
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Fourth section}
\clearpage
\section!{First appendix}
\blindtext[10]
\clearpage
\section!{Second appendix}
\subsection{First}
\blindtext[10]

\section!{Third appendix} \label{thirdapp:thirdchap}
\blindtext[10]

\section{Fifth section} % Will be ignored

\end{document}
```

[image]