# Insert subappendices in minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, minitoc

I'm using the document class `book` for my manuscript, together with `minitoc` and `appendix` packages (in the way provided by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120723)). The [minitoc package documentation](ftp://ftp.nsu.ru/mirrors/ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minitoc/minitoc-fr.pdf) section 2.20 tells us to use `\adjustmtc` for both package to work together, but by doing so, the appendices are no longer present in the minitoc of the chapter where they belong.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\minitoc
\section{Section one}
\section{Section two}
\begin{subappendices}
\adjustmtc     % So that appendix toc doesn't go into next chapter's minitoc
\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}
\end{subappendices}
\end{document}
```

I've put an overview of what you get.

[image: The minitoc I obtain]

What I would really like is the `minitoc` to show a line "Appendix" in the minitoc right after "1.2 Section two", followed by the lines "First appendix" and "Second appendix" with the corresponding pages.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `\chapter*` and `\addcontentsline` in the `subappendices` environment confuses `minitoc`.

Rather add it at the `section` level, that seems to be a better approach!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}



\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
  \clearpage
  \section*{Appendices}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
  \counterwithin{figure}{section}
  \counterwithin{table}{section}
}


\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\minitoc
\section{Section one}
\section{Section two}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}
\end{subappendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My PhD is now finished, corrected and printed, but thanks anyway :) hope it'll help others!

Comment: @jchd: Well, sorry for the late answer!