# Reversed order in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]

I'm compiling my thesis.

The middle is LaTeX code, the right panel is the PDF file and the left panel is the navigation panel seen in Adobe Reader.

The order is Chapter1-AppendixQ-Chapter2 in the TeX code and the order is preserved in the left panel. But Chapter 2 and  AppendixQ are reversed in the Table of Contents in the PDF file.
(2.5 Data analysis and 2.6 Conclusion are sections in the chapter 2, A1 and A2 are sections in 'appendicex.'
'AppendixQ' is inserted using `\addcontentsline` command because the appendix title is not shown in the Table of Contents.

I don't understand why `\include{chapter2}` comes earlier than `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{AppendixQ}`

Comment: Hi, can you add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), please?

Comment: @Troy It's too long to copy and paste here and it consists of multiple files (main tex file and each chapter). Could you tell me how I can post them?

Comment: Do take some time to read the link that I posted in the previous comment. In essence, a MWE should contain the least amount of code and packages which causes the problem. How I usually go about doing this is by creating a copy of the entire thesis file, and start removing code and packages that I think are irrelevant, recompiling each time to see if the problem is still there. Once you narrow down your latex code, then post it here.

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is based on a mix-up of deferred writing and immediate writing into the `.aux` file. Entries in the table of contents are first collected in the `.aux` files. At the next parsing of the `.aux` files, the entries are written to the `.toc` file with the same order as in the `.aux` files.

`\addcontentsline` or `\addtocontents` are deferred and written at the shipout time of the page, when the page number of the page is known. In opposite, `\include` immediately writes into the `.aux` file that now the `.aux` file for the included TeX file is included. Example:

```
\include{chapter_foobar}
```

writes

```
\@input{chapter_foobar.aux}
```

in the main `.aux` file.

### Analysis of the problem in the question

Main `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage % \include{chap1} calls \clearpage at the begin and end
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{AppendixQ}
\include{chap2}
\end{document}
```

`chap2.tex`:

```
\chapter{My 2nd paper}
```

`\addcontentsline` for "AppendixQ" is called at the start of a new page.
However, there is no material for a new page, when `\clearpage` is invoked by the following `\include`. Therefore, `\@input{chap2}` is immediately written by `\include{chap2}`. Then, later, when the next page is output, the entry for "AppendixQ" is written into the `.aux` file.

Main `.aux` file:

```
\@input{chap2.aux}
...
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{AppendixQ}{2}{chapter*.1}}
```

`chap2.aux` contains:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}My 2nd paper}{2}{chapter.1}}
```

### Solution

The solution is to move `\addcontentsline` into the following file `chap2.tex`:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{AppendixQ}

\chapter{My 2nd paper}
```

The main `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage % by \include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\end{document}
```

Now, the main `.aux` file contains

```
\@input{chap2.aux}
```

and `chap2.aux` contains the entries for the table of contents in the
correct order:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{AppendixQ}{2}{chapter*.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}My 2nd paper}{2}{chapter.1}}
```

Comment: Heiko, what a pitty, that I can only press once on the +1-button. :-/  Very well answered!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, appendix between chapters is required.

But since there is no MWE to work with,

the following answer: [Appendix after each chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/appendix-after-each-chapter)

should help you out.