# Interleaving alphabetically indexed appendices between the chapters

Tags: indexing, books, appendix

I want the appendix of say chapter 1 to occur right below it with its sections numbered 1.A, 1.B,...Then I want chapter 2 to start and its appendix should similarly start below it with sections numbered 2.A,2.B,...

Is this possible and if yes, then how?

Comment: You haven't given any clue about your input and document class. How are we supposed to answer?

Comment: I am using the MDT class. But I guess this question can be generically answered?

Comment: So you are using book class underneath.

Comment: You cannot assume that people here know what MDT-class means. I happen to know it, which is not a coincidence. But i would advise against using it. It doesn't do anything useful really.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120723/37907

Comment: Is there any news here?