# Including subsections of chapter-level appendices in main TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, appendices

I found this very helpful for adding chapter-level appendices:
[Appendix after each chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/appendix-after-each-chapter) . In this approach, each section in the subappendices environment appears in the main TOC as a section.

However, the TOC does not include subsections in these chapter-level appendices. I would like it to. This approach works:

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{1.A.1 Subsection Title} % etc.

but I have to manually include the numbering.

Is there a straightforward way to do this automatically? (Change depth of chapter-level appendices in main TOC?)

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that exhibits your problem and that we can compile to try and help you.

Not being a mind reader I'm guessing that your TOC does not normally include subsections. To get subsections listed in the TOC use `\setcounter{tocnumdepth}{2}`.

If this doesn't help then please help us with an MWE.