# Chapter-specific appendices with numbers related to the chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am using subappendices or an appendix after each chapter, following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/appendix-after-each-chapter). This is the Latex I am using

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
    \chapter*{Appendix}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
    \counterwithin{figure}{section}
    \counterwithin{table}{section}
}
```

which produces, for example, this:

[image]

However, the subappendices' titles do not have numbers. Ideally, they would and their sections would have numbers based on that number. What I had in mind would be like this:

```
3. Chapter Three
  3.1 Intro
  3.2 Some details
  3.3 Experiments
3A. Appendix
  3A.1 First subappendix of chapter 3
  3A.2 More details etc
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Your MWE does not compile and even if it did would not show the result you claim. We have no idea about how you have actually used the `appendix` package code facilities. Please provide an MWE that actually exhibits your problem. --- GOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the code from the early post so that:

- add “\thechapter A\quad” (or something like this) to \chapter*{...}
- add conveniently \addcontentsline to add “\thecahpter A” to appendix at TOC
- modify \thesection to print “A.”

This is done with:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
  \chapter*{\thechapter A\quad\appendixname}
  % add \numberline{<num-chap>A} to toc
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
    \protect\numberline{\thechapter A}\appendixname}
  \counterwithin{figure}{section}
  \counterwithin{table}{section}
}

% make section display <num-chap>A.<num-sec>
\apptocmd{\subappendices}{%
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter A.\arabic{section}}}{}{}
```

However, one sees that new appendix numberings (like 1A.2) are longer than previous (like 1.B) and toc lines have numbers too close to titles as you can see below:

[image: numbers too close to titles]

So you may increase these gaps. Look for the code of \l@chapter and \l@section in your class file (`book.cls` here) and change spacing, like below:

```
\makeatletter
% in \l@chapter change 1.5em by 2em
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.5em}{2em}{}{}
% in \l@section change {1.5em}{2.3em} by {2em}{2.8em}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{2em}{3em}}
\makeatother
```

The full code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
  \chapter*{\thechapter A\quad\appendixname}
  % add \numberline{<num-chap>A} to toc
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
    \protect\numberline{\thechapter A}\appendixname}
  \counterwithin{figure}{section}
  \counterwithin{table}{section}
}

% make section display <num-chap>A.<num-sec>
\apptocmd{\subappendices}{%
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter A.\arabic{section}}}{}{}

\makeatletter
% in \l@chapter change 1.5em by 2em
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.5em}{2em}{}{}
% in \l@section change {1.5em}{2.3em} by {2em}{2.8em}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{2em}{3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{A regular section}
\section{Another regular section}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{A regular section}
\section{Another regular section}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: final contents as desired]