# Customize subappendices heading and TOC indentation

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I came across this [excellent TeX.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120723/180731), demonstrating the use of subappendices.

I have intentionally pasted the nice MWE developed by user Gonzalo Medina there as a starting point for my queries. This is so that there is parity with this approach and others using it may benefit. It is pasted as below (with minor modifications).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{A regular section}
\section{Another regular section}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{A regular section}
\section{Another regular section}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Some title for an appendix}
\lipsum[4]
\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

### Questions

1. How can I customize the header of each chapter appendix to include the chapter number, e.g. **Appendices** changed to **Appendix - Chapter 1** for the Chapter One appendix?
2. How can I change the *indentation* of the Appendices header titles in the TOC. Specifically, so that the Appendix TOC title is aligned with the respective chapter TOC **title**, not the Chapter TOC number? More specifically, in the TOC, I would like the *text* **Appendices** to be left aligned with *text* **Test Chapter One** (so the letter **A** from **A**ppendices, aligns with the **T** from **T**est Chapter One), and then similarly for Test Chapter Two etc..

Any help on these would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
    \chapter*{Appendix - Chapter~\thechapter}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hspace{1.5em}Appendices  - Chapter~\thechapter}
    \counterwithin{figure}{section}
    \counterwithin{table}{section}
}
```

will get you

[image: a]

and

[image: b]

(the chapter number is "1" not "One")

Comment: Thanks - this is great. A follow up, how did you figure out the `1.5em`? Is it just by trial and error, or can that be derived programatically to always perfectly align. I ask because I had to change my actual document to `1.3em` using trial and error. Would be great to avoid this if possible, i.e., using `1.5em` for my actual LaTeX doc did align Appendix title with the Chapter title as needed, but using `1.3em` did.

Comment: @user4687531 In the standard classes book and report the chapter number is typeset in a box 1.5em wide. The number is hard coded but it can be changed, for example with the `tocloft `package. So in your actual document it will depend on the packages that customize the ToC and how.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I'll look into that. I've marked the question as solved.